# SQL Server 2008 - Fulltext search with multiple keywords and pagination

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm not a database guy (as this question will show). I'm trying to write a table-valued function that I can use with Linq To Sql in my ASP.NET web application.

Say I want to search for books where the Title or Summary might contain a number of keywords (eg "history of Australia").

I want to display x results at a time, so I need to be able to tell my function to "skip" and "take" a certain number of records.

Some books may be marked as "deleted". I don't want to return these.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SearchBooks
(
    @keywords nvarchar(50),
    @skip int,
    @take int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT TOP (@take)
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyFTS.RANK DESC) AS RowID,
         MyFTS.RANK as Relevance,
         [ID],
         [Title],
         [Summary]
    FROM [Book]
    JOIN CONTAINSTABLE ([Book], ([Title], [Summary]), @keywords, @take) AS MyFTS ON MyFTS.[KEY] = [Book].[ID]
   WHERE ([Book].[Deleted] = 0) 
     AND (MyFTS.[RowID] BETWEEN (@skip + 1) AND (@skip + @take))
ORDER BY MyFTS.RANK DESC
)
```

When I try to create this function SSMS gives me the error "Invalid column name 'RowID'".

I suppose I will also need to get the total number of matching records so I can setup pagination?

I'm hoping one of you SQL gurus can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference a column alias in the WHERE clause - use an inline view/derived table:

```
  SELECT x.rowid,
         x.relevance,
         x.id,
         x.title,
         x.summary
   FROM (SELECT TOP (@take)
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyFTS.RANK DESC) AS RowID,
                MyFTS.RANK as Relevance,
                [ID],
                [Title],
                [Summary]
           FROM [Book] b
           JOIN CONTAINSTABLE ([Book], ([Title], [Summary]), @keywords, @take) AS MyFTS ON MyFTS.[KEY] = b.id
          WHERE b.[Deleted] = 0) AS x
    WHERE x.[RowID] BETWEEN (@skip + 1) AND (@skip + @take))
ORDER BY x.relevance DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks OMG Ponies - that's exactly what I was after.
I've modified the function so that it also returns the total number of matching rows (TotalRows) and now I should be able to get pagination to work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SearchBooks
(
    @keywords nvarchar(50),
    @skip int,
    @take int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT TOP (@take) * FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (@take)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyFTS.RANK DESC) AS RowID,
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) as TotalRows,
            MyFTS.RANK as Relevance,
            [ID],
            [Title],
            [Summary]
        FROM [Book] b
        JOIN CONTAINSTABLE ([Book], ([Title], [Summary]), @keywords, @take) AS MyFTS ON MyFTS.[KEY] = b.[ID]
        WHERE b.[Deleted] = 0
    ) AS x
    WHERE x.[RowID] BETWEEN (@skip + 1) AND (@skip + @take)
    ORDER BY x.relevance DESC
)
```